# Definition of Operation

Tags: definition, foundations, binary-operations

What are operations in Mathematics? I do not find it formally defined anywhere. What is the difference between operation and function? Earlier I thoght operations are just binary operations. But later I learnt that rotation is also a operation. Can we define operation?

Comment: An operation can be thought of as a function.  I thinks it's intuitively misleading to do so though.  A binary function is a .... way to assign... a mapping...oh, screw it! a *function* ... that maps any two elements to an element.  An operation in general doesn't nescessarily require exactly two elements.

Comment: If you say that a rotation is a operation, then you must have defined the term operation prior to that statement. There is no formal definition of operations that I know of. They are defined in a certain context. For example, if you are dealing with groups, then you have a operation $\cdot$ that is defined as a map $\cdot:G\times G\rightarrow G$ that satisfies certain conditions. Differentiation can be viewed as an operator $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}:C^1(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow C(\mathbb{R}):f\mapsto \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}$. All things you'd call operations are defined similarly.

Comment: Okay, one difference (sort of) between an operation and a function.  A function may map from any set to any set.  An operation generally is understood to map elements of a set to the same set.  Technically, if viewed as a function an operation maps a multiple cross product (the set of ordered n-tuples) to the set: SxSx...xS-->S.

Comment: See [Operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)#General_description).

Comment: So operation is just a special kind of function.... nothing specific

Comment: @fleablood could a operation be thought of as a "usefull" function?